# multiple robots in navigation_stage

Tags: ros, rviz, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
can any one tell me how to navigate multiple robots in navigation_stage. I am unable to find the multi_robot.vcg file for multiple robots.
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9900/multiple-robots-in-navigation_stage/) by [Ali Abdul Khaliq](https://answers.ros.org/users/414/ali-abdul-khaliq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Ubuntu at least, you should be able to install the navigation_stage package through apt. First, follow the [ROS Installation Instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation).

Next, you should be able to run a simple "`sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-navigation-tutorials`" to install the navigation_tutorials stack which includes the [navigation_stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation_stage) package.

If you're not running Ubuntu, you'll want to use [rosinstall](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall) or mercurial directly to pull the navigation_tutorials package from https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/tutorials.

After this, it should just be a matter of running `move_base_multi_robot.launch` to see an example of navigation with multiple robots.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1